# How to use the Raster source type?

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers-3

**TL;DR:** How can I use the Raster source in OL3? How to display anything using it?
A simple working example would be perfect.

==============================================

I'm trying to use the ol.source.Raster to visualise elevation data.

What I first tried to do though was making the whole map a certain colour as follows:

```
var bing = new ol.source.BingMaps({key: '%key%', imagerySet: 'Aerial'});
var raster = new ol.source.Raster({
    sources: [bing],
    operation: function(pixels, data) {
        return (0, 255, 0, 128);
    },
});
map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({source: bing}),
        new ol.layer.Image({source: raster})
    ],
    target: 'ol-map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([-1, 52], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 6
    })
});
```

I expected the whole map to be green.

However, this did nothing. As in, it displayed the bing layer, but not the raster layer. Or maybe the raster layer didn't consist of anything as a result of this code, I don't know.

I've tried looking at [the](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/raster.html) [examples](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/region-growing.html) on the ol3 website and they've not been helpful. In fact, upon clicking the Edit button on them and being taken to JSFiddle, they don't seem to render anything. Maybe that's an issue with JSFiddle. So I've copied over the supposed source code, and tried running that in a .html file. The ol3 map object loaded, but nothing else, interestingly enough.

Context-wise, I would use the Geolocation API within ol3 to calculate elevation colours for tiles and render them in the raster layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value return in the function `operation` must be the array (You can refer to the link  http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.html#.RasterOperation). You can change the raster

```
var raster = new ol.source.Raster({
sources: [bing],
operation: function(pixels, data) {
    return [0, 255, 0, 128];
},
});
```

Comment: You have got to be kidding me... -_-

Comment: I still don't understand why the ol3 examples don't render anything though o.O